# Combining node.js project with visual studio project

Tags: asp.net, node.js, visual-studio, webforms, webrtc

I have a WebRTC application (two way webcam) hosted on node.js and a web form application designed in visual studio for web. Just wondering how to combine both of them to be on the same page.

Comment: so are you making this web app in ado.net or asp.net mvc try this site you will get every answer you want https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/